# Map JSON object - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am a getting a json object as a response and console log shows the response like this

```
MyFormName: Array(5)
0: {question: "Q1", type: "star"}
1: {question: "Q1", type: "star"}
2: {question: "Q1", type: "star"}
3: {question: "Q1", type: "star"}
4: {question: "Q1", type: "star"}
```

How can i map through this object so i can show data in each object?

I have tried something like this. I have my json object in a state `fullForm` and tried the following approach

```
return Object.keys(this.state.fullForm).map((item, key) => {

      return (
        <div className="overflow_hidden" key={key}>
          <div>{key + 1}</div>
          <div>{item.question}</div>

        </div>
      )

      });
```

But here the value i get for `item` is `MyFormName`. I want to map the objects in `MyFormName`. How can i do this?

Comment: Can you try `this.state.fullForm.MyFormName`

Comment: `Object.keys(this.state.fullForm). MyFormName.map`

Comment: MyFormName can be changed according to the response type. So i cannot directly use the name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.state.fullForm[Object.keys(this.state.fullForm)[0]].map(item, key) => {
  //your logic here
})
```

It will get you the first item of fullForm which is in this example MyFormName's value as in an array and then you do `.map`